# How to send illegal XML elements in the body of a http request?

Tags: java, parsing, post, sax

I am making a POST and posting data in `xml` format, but I want to pass values like `<`, `>`, and `@`.

```
<test name="test">#,#,<</test>
```

I have a problem with the `<` and `>` characters. Is there any way to pass these values? I cannot change the input format.

Comment: can you URLEncode the XML ?

Comment: but then I will have all post data be encoded. I guess you mean encode for XML?

Comment: in your POST management you can just URLDecode then. Just be sure to use form/urlencoded as content type and send the xml as a POST parametrer (e.g. xmlData=URLEncode.encode(yourXmlString); )

Comment: You can use StringEscapeUtils from commons-lang: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml11(java.lang.String)

Comment: I decided to post in in a encoded format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) to wrap the XML content.

```
<![CDATA[
    XML  content
]]>
```